# Wildfly 10.1.0.Final ManagedExecutorService causes to increase live threads number

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, wildfly, executorservice

Wildfly 10.1.0.Final ManagedExecutorService causes to increase live threads number

I have tried the same configuration on Wildfly 15

I have a Timer class executed in every 10 minutes. I call a method of stateless session bean in this timer.

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;

@Timeout
public void timeOut() {
    executorBean.executeParallels();
}
```

In ExecutorBean, i use ManagedExecutorService and call 10000 times to do doSomething.

```
@Stateless (name="ExecutorBean")
ExecutorBean implements ExecutorLocal {

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService executorService;

    public void executeParallels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Future<Void> result = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    doSomething();
                    return "executed";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my standalone.conf file:

```
<managed-executor-services>
<managed-executor-service name="default"
    jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default"
    context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000"
    core-threads="50" max-threads="50" keepalive-time="5000"/>
</managed-executor-services>
```

I can deploy and run the code, but when i check the Wildfly Management console (Standalone Server -> JVM ) I can see that the number of live threads are contiounsly increasing in time.

Thread numbers should be the same over time.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by "I can see that the number of live threads are contiounsly increasing in time."?

Comment: I am using jcm or wildfly management console. On these screens i see that the number of live threads continously increase.  Thread names start with "Timer-". Those threads become 3000 in minutes. Also i see that 50 managed executor service threads as i expected.

Comment: You should see 50 managed executor service threads based on the configuration. I'm not too familiar with the EJB timer configuration, but that could be correct too depending on the configuration.